# How to add a hint popup to a TextComponent?

Tags: codenameone, hint

TL;DR The title says it, details follow.

I'm having a form like

```
Bank: Bank of Neverland
Customer ID(?): Peter Pan
```

except for that it's real and the "Customer ID" is something provided by the bank. The bank may call it differently (so I change the label to e.g., "User name") and to prevent confusion, a lengthy hint may be needed. So I imagine using a question mark-like icon (`(?)`) popping the hint on click.

There are more fields which need a hint popup. I'd be fine with placing them elsewhere in the row.

However, the `InputComponent.lbl` is package-private and I can't see any way to attach the icon. I'm aware of `TextComponent#hint(String hint)`, but it only allows for a rather short text, while we sometimes need a rather lengthy explanations (and that's not something we could change).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR we didn't implement that yet. Label is meant for the hint label not for that. You can probably add a `?` button next to the component and show a popup or just add a label below.

What you are looking for is #1 in this image taken from [here](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy):

[image: material UI]

We implemented #2 which should make implementing #1 a bit easier... At least in theory but it won't adapt to the iOS mode of the UI which looks rather different. That was the main blocker for the implementation.

As a short term solution you can just add a `SpanLabel` below the text component or add a question mark button next to it.

Alternatively you can enhance the error label functionality in our code to support  "helper text" which you might show as a popup on iOS or as a floating hint in the bottom of the screen there. Then submit that as a pull request to the project. You can also file an RFE we are under heavy workload so I'm not sure when we'll get around to it.

Comment: I didn't touch this for one year, now I'm back. What I'd need is logically #1 from your image, but my text is far too long, so I need #3  (trailing icon, not as error indicator, but for popping up a multiline hint). Two questions: • I was looking for `TextComponent#setErrorMessage` or alike and found nothing - how is it called? • Doing myself - where to start? Overlay, absolutely positioned component, custom painting, ...???

Comment: We have a feature called `action` now which allows you to set a non-error icon on a text component and get an event when a user clicks it. We also have `descriptionMessage` which lets you define a message that isn't an error message. About the multi-line nature of such a message I'm not sure how that would be best implemented. Maybe a toast message when the icon is clicked?